# Why am I only getting 2 objects for PFFile, but 10 for String?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am importing a profile picture as well as other information such as name. There are 10 objects, and I get 10 names when importing from Parse, but I only get two photos. I can ENSURE 100% that the column names are correct AND there are images in the columns. I don't know if this error has any relevance, but I am guessing it does [image: Error]

```
let imagequery = PFQuery(className: "Animal")
    imagequery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
        for object in objects!{

            if let thumbNail = object["Pic"] as? PFFile{
            thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    //image object implementation
                    self.tableImage.append(image!)
                    print(image)
                    }

                })
            }
            if let name = object["Name"] as? String{
                self.Name.append(name)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.collectionview.reloadData()
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar once happened to me when I imported rows from another parse app, images just didn't work because the parse files was not located in this database. I cleaned the column and uploaded images again and it worked.